# Cannot replace fragement with new fragment

Tags: android

I have a tabbed `activity`, i have tabhost hosting three `fragments` in three `tabs`.

on `onclick` of some buttons in one tab, another fragment would replace the old `fragment`. I created a container `<linearlayout>` in my main `activity` to replace that with new `fragment`.

Things are working fine, but all the three `fragments` are getting replaced with the same `fragment` that is hosted in the first tab when i dynamically create a container to replace. I think all are sharing the same container. Is it that i have to create three separate LinearLayouts and host different fragemnts in them and link each one.

Can anyone provide with a very simple example three tabs and one button in one of the tabs clicking which replaces one of the fragment with a new fragment. Would be really thankful.

Comment: Some code would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to share your code so we can help

Comment: create another container in tab fragmenrt and add sub fragment of tabfragment to that  container....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android Studio generated TabbedActivity, you only need to do something like this in your `onCreateView()` in the Fragment.  If you've created your own Activity & Fragment, you still use this but you will need to make sure to set the argument when creating/replacing fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView;
    switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
        case 1:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
            Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
            // other stuff for this layout here
            break;

        case 2:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
            // other stuff for this layout here
            break;

        case 3:
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
            // other stuff for this layout here
            break;
    }
    return rootView;
}
```